# Phonegap : Camera view with background image

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap with Sencha Touch to get camera functionality. But instead of the default camera view, I want a picture with transparent background to be overlaid upon the live camera view. Similar to below example where a dinosaur image has been overlaid upon the camera view image.

[image]

Can you tell me whether this feature can be achieved with Phonegap or in any other way?

Comment: I think creating a phonegap plugin may work. Is there any existing plugin or solution? I am looking for one.

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved but it requires a bit of native code and a simple trick.

You need to set the phonegap container to transparent, and also add a surface behind your phonegap container.

You use native code to initialize the camera view and then phonegap renders atop of it.

A good example can be found at: http://git.libresoft.es/ARviewer-phoneGap/