# Background Camera in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to display a camera preview in the background of my application. I code with cordova and I was wondering if it's possible to do that directly with a known plugin of cordova or if I have to implement one. (I'm not talking about the camera functionality in which we can take photos, but just the camera preview without anything in which we just see the view provided by the camera)

In this last situation, how do I do this? I need this camera preview to really be in the background of other elements on the screen (I'm developping a local-based geolocation augmented reality application).

Do you have any idea how to implement this, especially in android?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please help! I need to know how to do this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap : Camera view with background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268669/phonegap-camera-view-with-background-image)